# Array to string sometimes concatenates fewer values

Tags: postgresql, null, array, concat

```
array_to_string(array_agg(array_to_string(array[
            highlights,exceptions,inter_note,inter_status::text
           ,comp_note,comp_status::text,hard_note,hard_status::text]
        ,'|#|'::text))
     ,'|*|'::text) as status
```

By executing the above query the `status` should contain 8 values separated by `|#|` or `|*|`. But in some cases it returns only 3, 4 or 6 values. I need to get all 8 values weather the record is empty or not.

Example:

> original array: `[|#||#||#||#|Complete|#||#|Undefined|#||#|Undefined]`
>
> some cases: `[|#||#||#|PASS|#|Complete|#|Undefined|#|Undefined]`
>
> another case: `[Complete|#|Undefined|#|Undefined]`

Any idea why some array elements are missing?

Comment: No it is psql @McNets

Comment: Questions like this one need to disclose table definition (with data types and constraints) and Postgres version.

Comment: BTW, "[psql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/psql/info)" is the name of the default command line interface. The RDBMS is called "PostgreSQL" or "Postgres" (or "pg" if you need it ultra-short). Never "psql".

Comment: Do you want "Undefined" to return `null` or the empty string? If there is no value do you want the empty string or `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that every field has a default value by using [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html).

> ```
> create table t (highlights varchar(10), 
>                 exceptions varchar(10), 
>                 inter_note varchar(10),
>                 inter_status int,
>                 comp_note varchar(10), 
>                 comp_status int,
>                 hard_note varchar(10),
>                 hard_status int);
>
> insert into t values ('a','b','c',1,'d',2,'e',3),('',null,'f',4,null,5,'g',null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select array_to_string(
>          array_agg(
>            array_to_string(
>              array[coalesce(highlights, ''),
>                    coalesce(exceptions, ''),
>                    coalesce(inter_note,inter_status::text, ''),
>                    coalesce(comp_note, ''),
>                    coalesce(comp_status::text, ''),
>                    coalesce(hard_note, ''),
>                    coalesce(hard_status::text, '')],'|#|'::text)),'|*|'::text) as status
> from   t;
> ```
>
> ```
> | status                                            |
> | :------------------------------------------------ |
> | a|#|b|#|c|#|d|#|2|#|e|#|3|*||#||#|f|#||#|5|#|g|#| |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=806fbcfc3ea5c5f7c85dbdbf0aad591a)*

Answer (score 2):

The **core problem** here is that **`array_to_string()`** omits **NULL** values unless you **add another parameter** providing the desired null string. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> concatenates array elements using supplied delimiter **and optional null string**

Bold emphasis mine. So:

```
SELECT string_agg(array_to_string(ARRAY[highlights
                                      , exceptions
                                      , inter_note,inter_status::text
                                      , comp_note
                                      , comp_status::text
                                      , hard_note
                                      , hard_status::text]
                                , '|#|', 'NULL')   -- provide NULL representation here
                , '|*|') AS status
FROM   tbl;
```

And an outer `string_agg()` is simpler than `array_to_string(array_agg())`.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2fd46975e29396df3f53ba39808434fe)* (based on McNets' fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

## Pl/Perl

I'm guessing you want `Undefined` to return `null` and the lack of a value to return an empty string, but please clarify here. I imagine this is faster than the plpgsql version,

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plperl;

CREATE FUNCTION stupid_delim(text)
RETURNS text[]
AS $$
  return [ map {$_ eq 'Undefined' ? undef : $_} split /\|#\|/, $_[0] ]
$$ LANGUAGE plperl
IMMUTABLE;

SELECT stupid_delim(ln)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('|#||#||#||#|Complete|#||#|Undefined|#||#|Undefined'),
  ('|#||#||#|PASS|#|Complete|#|Undefined|#|Undefined'),
  ('Complete|#|Undefined|#|Undefined')
) AS f(ln);
```